# Is it possible to free space used by docker container on restart?

Tags: docker, selenium

I am trying to fetch mass of urls with Selenium WebDriver (selenium/standalone-chrome:96.0 image), running in container on EC2 instance with 30GB storage. I put many efforts to avoid disc space leaking during this proccess, but finally gave up. So after a while container run out of space and i get error from WebDriver like `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot create temp dir for user data dir`

As workaround I can force container exit after a while, so docker will restart container (with restart:always policy), but disc space is not reclaimed, and sooner or later docker restart manager throws error like
`restartmanger wait error: mount /dev/mapper/docker-259:3-394503-72f7b76024003665f890079f6f681414587483fa2f30e0f080c027cd516ba7d2:/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/72f7b76024003665f890079f6f681414587483fa2f30e0f080c027cd516ba7d2: input/output error\nFailed to mount;` and leaves container stopped.

Are there any technique to reclaim disk space on container restart?

UPDATE
creating/closing webdriver, performed after each `driver.get()`

```
def create_webdriver():
    global driver
    try:
        logger.info("WebDriver: creating...")
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("start-maximized")
        options.add_argument("enable-automation")
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
        options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        options.add_argument("--disable-browser-side-navigation")
        options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    except Exception:
        logger.exception("WebDriver: exception while creating, can not manage, exiting.")
        exit(1)


def close_webdriver():
    global driver
    if driver is not None:
        driver.quit()
    driver = None
```

UPDATE2

It seems that there are no disk space leakage, but some issues with docker devicemapper fs on EC2 instance. I carefully investigate disk and docker space usage during the proccess, and find no issues

```
devtmpfs          16323728          120 16323608            1% /dev
tmpfs             16333664            0 16333664            0% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme0n1p1     8189348      1919080  6170020           24% /

TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          9         1         9.033GB   8.571GB (94%)
Containers      8         6         144.8MB   -2B (0%)
Local Volumes   0         0         0B        0B
Build Cache     0         0         0B        0B
```

but anyway container feels bad

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot create temp dir for user data dir
```

and exit, docker can't restart it and there are errors in `/var/log/docker`

```
time="2021-12-26T01:36:06.030765815Z" level=error msg="Driver devicemapper couldn't return diff size of container 258399ca6d95cb3510e5e02fec9253b2f22852e8a3553cfad8774b9f913ed279: Failed to mount; dmesg: <3>[ 3761.830462] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-8, logical block 2185471, lost async page write\n<4>[ 3761.839429] JBD2: recovery failed\n<3>[ 3761.843623] EXT4-fs (dm-8): error loading journal\n: mount /dev/mapper/docker-259:3-394503-26a311e2927d080ef4895f43d7dcd6ddaa26e5c0d8e71b6eb46bcdc8d1601194:/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/26a311e2927d080ef4895f43d7dcd6ddaa26e5c0d8e71b6eb46bcdc8d1601194: input/output error"
time="2021-12-26T01:36:25.009915383Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=f47ab38bdab172205bd30c3cdbc6723162e4422ef4dcda23f6fec0ac99a20035 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/delete type="*events.TaskDelete"
time="2021-12-26T01:36:25.010710566Z" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=f47ab38bdab172205bd30c3cdbc6723162e4422ef4dcda23f6fec0ac99a20035
time="2021-12-26T01:36:25.010797187Z" level=error msg="copy shim log" error="read /proc/self/fd/36: file already closed"
time="2021-12-26T01:36:28.788036177Z" level=warning msg="error locating sandbox id c1e0abc725ee3e88f388042a34b8e46db09a8fd8024774862899d0f7d9af721b: sandbox c1e0abc725ee3e88f388042a34b8e46db09a8fd8024774862899d0f7d9af721b not found"
time="2021-12-26T01:36:28.788396052Z" level=error msg="Error unmounting device 8de02009e67a0fea87313b35b117eaed6cf654837532e04ce16a6fc0846d1954: invalid argument" storage-driver=devicemapper
time="2021-12-26T01:36:28.788426923Z" level=error msg="error unmounting container" container=f47ab38bdab172205bd30c3cdbc6723162e4422ef4dcda23f6fec0ac99a20035 error="invalid argument"
time="2021-12-26T01:36:28.789562261Z" level=error msg="f47ab38bdab172205bd30c3cdbc6723162e4422ef4dcda23f6fec0ac99a20035 cleanup: failed to delete container from containerd: no such container"
time="2021-12-26T01:36:28.794739546Z" level=error msg="restartmanger wait error: mount /dev/mapper/docker-259:3-394503-8de02009e67a0fea87313b35b117eaed6cf654837532e04ce16a6fc0846d1954:/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/8de02009e67a0fea87313b35b117eaed6cf654837532e04ce16a6fc0846d1954: input/output error\nFailed to mount; dmesg: <3>[ 3784.574178] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-10, logical block 1048578, lost async page write\n<4>[ 3784.583183] JBD2: recovery failed\n<3>[ 3784.587446] EXT4-fs (dm-10): error loading journal\n\ngithub.com/docker/docker/daemon/graphdriver/devmapper.(*DeviceSet).MountDevice\n\t/builddir/build/BUILD/docker-20.10.7-3.71.amzn1/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/graphdriver/devmapper/deviceset.go:2392\ngithub.com/docker/docker/daemon/graphdriver/devmapper.(*Driver).Get\n\t/builddir/build/BUILD/docker-20.10.7-3.71.amzn1/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/graphdriver/devmapper/driver.go:208\ngithub.com/docker/docker/layer.(*referencedRWLayer).Mount\n\t/builddir/build/BUILD/docker-20.10.7-3.71.amzn1/src/github.com/docker/docker/layer/mounted_layer.go:104\ngithub.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).Mount\n\t/builddir/build/BUILD/docker-20.10.7-3.71.amzn1/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/daemon.go:1320\ngithub.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).conditionalMountOnStart\n\t/builddir/build/BUILD/docker-20.10.7-3.71.amzn1/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/daemon_unix.go:1360\ngithub.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).containerStart\n\t/builddir/build/BUILD/docker-20.10.7-3.71.amzn1/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/start.go:145\ngithub.com/docker/docker/daemon.(*Daemon).handleContainerExit.func1\n\t/builddir/build/BUILD/docker-20.10.7-3.71.amzn1/src/github.com/docker/docker/daemon/monitor.go:84\nruntime.goexit\n\t/usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374"
```

SOLVED

It was really issue with default AMI Linux docker configuration with devicemapper storage driver on EC2 instance. Clean install docker on Ubuntu 18.04 with overlay2 storage driver solves the issue completely.

Comment: Are you using the same webdriver session or creating a new one? Incase creating a new one are you using `driver.quit()`

Comment: was trying both approach. Even while doing driver.quit() after each url fetched there are some leaks, I can't detect where.

Comment: Can you update the question with your code snippet where you initialize and quit the driver?